# Finding out more stable conformer via molecular orbital interaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, conformers

[image: 2‐chlorooxane conformers]

Out of these two, which one is more stable? I'm unable to imagine the orientation of the lone pairs of O and ABMO of C and Cl bond.

Any tips to tackle these kind of problems?

Comment: Try writing the lone pairs of the two heteroatoms as if they were attached to the atoms by bonds, in a tetrahedral geometry. What structure minimizes LP-LP interaction? :)

Comment: @The_Vinz Based on your idea, I would say Cl in axial position is favorable. I also want to look at it another way. Can we consider the pi type overlap between lone pair of O and sigma asterisk bond of C and Cl?

Comment: Yep, the answer is that: chlorine in axial position minimizes the so-called 1-3 diaxial interaction between the lone pairs, and is thus more stable (from a substantially qualitative AM1 calculation, around 15 kJ/mol lower in energy). As to the molecular orbitals, I confess that personally I couldn't extimate that interaction "on paper"

Comment: Search for "anomeric effect", you will probably find a number of websites explaining this in some detail.